# How to compare two dynamic variables in JavaScript (React-Native)?

Tags: javascript, react-native, variables, compare

I am trying to compare these two variables:
`res_id;`  and  `rest_id;`

likes this:

```
if(res_id == rest_id){
console.log("THESE VALUES ARE THE SAME", rest_id);
}
```

whenever any of their values are the same I want to print something but it doesn't work using the above statement.

Remember they are dynamic.

**console.log() :**

```
    [14:21:08] I | ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'PRINT THE REST-ID:', '1'
                             └ 'PRINT THE RES-ID:', undefined

[14:21:08] I | ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'PRINT THE REST-ID:', 'Aura1'
                             └ 'PRINT THE RES-ID:', undefined

[14:21:08] I | ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'PRINT THE REST-ID:', 'jeta1'
                             └ 'PRINT THE RES-ID:', undefined

[14:21:08] I | ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'PRINT THE REST-ID:', undefined
                             └ 'PRINT THE RES-ID:', '1'

[14:21:08] I | ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'PRINT THE REST-ID:', undefined
                             └ 'PRINT THE RES-ID:', '10'
```

Comment: what do these variables hold? Numbers, strings, arrays, object... ?

Comment: they contain strings, but does it really matter if they contain numbers for example? i dont think there would be a difference in the way we compare them.

Comment: it would matter if they were arrays or objects, that's why I asked

Comment: any chance you could show more of your code (like how and where these variables are set). Looks like the above should work fine

Comment: you should check `console.log(res_id, rest_id)` this help identify why condition not getting pass.

Comment: Apart from cases that are stated by @NickParsons, there's many ways to compare different types. In your case it doesn't matter, but just to further the perspective of the question: objects and arrays compare by identity, strings can be compared using `===` or using constant time string-comparison (i.e. for passwords), numbers could be actually floats that just don't compare well with `===`. Different cases for different types.

Comment: if you could be more specific on the type of values you want to check, then people can come up with some solid solution. As the question and information provided are not sufficient, the scope of the answer is vast

Comment: @NickParsons its hard to show more code because these variables are set after looping through an array which is done in a component called Carousel.

Comment: @NickParsons check the edited question, i added the console.log

Comment: @jagad89 see the edited quesiton

Comment: Your console log shows that one of them is always undefined, so there's some logic error in how you're setting the values. With this, the only way they would be the same is if both are undefined.

Comment: @zaytrix I want to check if any of them are equal. So, sometimes they will not be equal.

Comment: Is there any case in which they are equal and the comparison fails anyway? Because it should work

Comment: there are cases where it wont be a res_id same as a rest_id but there are multiple cases when there will be matches. I just wanna find the matches and usually I have used an if statement in these cases but somehow its not wokring here.

Answer (score 0):

You've provided no view of your overall function, but i'm assuming it's a react component in which case you can use useEffect to perform an action when any of those values change.

```
useEffect((), {
    if (res_id === rest_id) {
     console.log('they are equal')
    }
    else {
      console.log('they are not equal')
    }
  }, [res_id, rest_id])
```